# Adding an import statement to Typescript source using the Compiler API

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a way to insert an import statement using the Typescript compiler API. Here's what I'd like to do

Before:

```
class Simple extends Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <style jsx>{`
          div {
            background: green;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

After:

```
import { Component } from 'react' // inserted

class Simple extends Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <style jsx>{`
          div {
            background: green;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm using: Typescript 2.4.1.

Comment: What environment do you want to do this from ? Command line ? Vs Code ? Do you have any existing code ?

Comment: I'd like to be able to transform this within a webpack loader. I do have existing code, but it's like ~200LOC. There doesn't seem to be a any way to append nodes at the top-level SourceFile AST node.